# `System.println.out` doesn't work

Tags: java, printing

I am new to Java and trying to develop a program.
I have the following code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.println.out("Watch on youtube: Mickey en de stomende drol");
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. I get an error stacktrace that `println` isn't recognized, how come this happens?

Comment: `System.out.println`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `System.out.println()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

switch the words `println` and `out`. you call in wrong order:

```
System.out.println("Watch on youtube: Mickey en de stomende drol");
```

Answer (score 0):

`out` is a static reference variable to `PrintStream` class in `System` class. And `println()` is an instance method of `PrintStream` class.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println("Watch on youtube: Mickey en de stomende drol");

Answer (score 0):

You should write System.out.println() instead of System.println.out()

Answer (score 0):

Here out is the static referenced variable of PrintStream class and println(),print() are methods of PrintStream class so you should call those methods like 
System.out.print("Watch on youtube: Mickey en de stomende drol");
System.out.println("Watch on youtube: Mickey en de stomende drol");